# Chicken scheme (use) and (import) in modules not working

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I've experienced this problem in several projects, but this test case removes everything that is unecessary to understanding the problem. I've been using it to figure out what's wrong:

So I have a directory with 2 files in it, `foo.scm`, and `bar.scm`:

```
;;;foo.scm
(module foo (baz)
  (import chicken scheme)
  (define (baz)
    (display "bazzer!\n")))
```

---

```
;;;bar.scm
(module baz (quux)
  (import chicken scheme)
  (use foo)
  (define (quux)
    (baz)
    (display "quuxed!\n")))
```

baz.scm fails to run in csi with this error:

```
Error: (import) during expansion of (import ...) - cannot import from undefined module: foo
```

I've checked the docs: `use` should load the code into memory, and then `import` it. I've even run `require`, the function `use` uses to load code, separately. It runs without a hitch, it's just `import` that fails. I also tried to import the code in `csi`. `use` doesn't work, but `require` followed by `import` does, even though that should be equivalent to `use`.

In short, I'm hopelessly confused. Can anybody explain what's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(use foo)` and `(import foo)` both will try to load a file called `foo.import.so` or `foo.import.scm`.  This is a so-called "import library", which contains the necessary information to compile a module.

This is comparable to a "header file" for C, and it's needed in order to make separate compilation possible. For example, in case of cross-compilation, it will be necessary to load the **import library** into the compiler on the **build machine**, but the library **itself** will be loaded into the program on the **target machine**.

You can generate this import file using `-J` or `-j foo` when compiling foo using `csc`.

The `require` procedure works at runtime, which means it's more like `load` than like `use`.  I think you're confusing it with `require-extension`, which is like `use`.

Comment: No, I was using require, because it's the procedure that require-extension calls under the hood. Check chickadee.

Comment: also, I tried this, and got: `Error: unbound variable: foo#baz` do I need to add another compilation, or something? I don't know.

Comment: If you got that error, you probably only used `import`; it indicates that it knows that `baz` should be resolved to the `foo` module, but it doesn't have the actual definition itself (meaning it hasn't loaded the code yet).  You'll need to `load` (or `require`) **and** `import` (or just `use`).